Calculating the 3 Year and 5 Year Sharpe Ratio of a Fund Using Monthly Returns
I am trying to calculate the Sharpe ratio of monthly returns of 5 years for a mutual fund. My process so far has been as follows:

Calculate the excess monthly returns ie take each months returns and subtract the monthly risk free rate (used Fed Funds rate at start of month divided by 12)
I then took the std dev of these monthly returns and got to 4.59
I then divided 1 by 2 and multiplied by sqrt 12
My answer came out as 0.50 which does not seem correct to me

I am still early on my journey with this stuff does anyone perhaps have any pointers as to where I went wrong?

A 0.50 Sharpe Ratio for a mutual fund seems plausible to me. The process you describe seems correct. A monthly standard deviation of 4.59 percent (corresponding to 15.9 percent a year) seems plausible also for a cautious, diversified equity MF. What causes you to disbelieve the results?
